# How to set the value for an input type=password html object in C#

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to confirm a Login Page with a C# Tool and I noticed a pretty strange behavior. I'can set the username put not the password.

It's a very simple page with only 3 inputs in one form.

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
    <td align="right"><p class="bold">Username:</p></td>
    <td><input size="15" maxlength="15" type="text" name="j_username"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"><p class="bold">Password</p></td>
    <td><input type="password" size="15" maxlength="15" name="j_password"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
```

As I said setting the username works fine but i can't set the password.

My C# code looks like this^

```
private void btn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _webBrowser.Document.Forms.Count; i++)
    {
        HtmlElement element = _webBrowser.Document.Forms[i];

        if (element != null)
        {
            _webBrowser.Document.All["j_username"].SetAttribute("value", txt_username.Text);
            _webBrowser.Document.All["j_password"].SetAttribute("value", txt_password.Text);

            var test = _webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Count;

            _webBrowser.Document.Forms[i].InvokeMember("btnSubmit");
            element = _webBrowser.Document.Forms[i];
        } 
    }
}
```

Do I have to do something special cause it is a type=password ?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the type to 'text'

Comment: That would defeat the whole purpose of a password textbox

Comment: Acutally I would try to look if this is the problem. But I do not have access to page definition..

Comment: True the only other thing I can think of is to have a little JS that can store the password to string and replace onKeyOut with *... I am new to this so this may totally be wrong..